# Defining a method for data input check and calling it doesn't help, android

Tags: java, android, methods

I have more fields in an app that the user must complete, before the app does some math with that data. Because of the possibility to skip one field and then the app will crash, I inserted some fail-safe triggers.
example :

```
EditText vZeitE = (EditText) findViewById(vZeit);
    if (vZeitE.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        vZeitE.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(vZeitE, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        vZeitE.setError(getString(R.string.ErrStringVZeitMissing));
    } else {
```

First take the field content, check it's length, if other then 0, proceede for the next field check, if length is 0, means no data was entered and user will receive a error message and the cursor will go to the empty field, forcing him to enter value.

now, doing this over and over and over again (because it is used in almost all methodes) started to pi** me off. I said I could try to define a method for every field check and just call it in another method when I need it.
So I have done this :

Here I define the method :

```
public void checkBeginnTime() {
    EditText EtimpAnfang = (EditText) findViewById(timpAnfang);
    if (EtimpAnfang.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        EtimpAnfang.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(EtimpAnfang, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        EtimpAnfang.setError(getString(R.string.ErrStringAnfangZeitMissing));
    }
}
```

here I replace the old code with the new method :

```
findViewById(R.id.buttoSaveCalcOR)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sOptionSave) + " (" + getString(R.string.sButOhneRust) + ") ");
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.sConfirmOption));

                    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.sJa), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            EditText edTimpAnfang = (EditText) findViewById(timpAnfang);
                            checkBeginnTime();
                            //  if (edTimpAnfang.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            //      edTimpAnfang.requestFocus();
                            //      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            //      imm.showSoftInput(edTimpAnfang, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                            //      edTimpAnfang.setError(getString(R.string.noinput));
                            //  } else {
                           EditText EaufGesSt = (EditText) findViewById(aufGesSt);
                            checkTotalOrder();
                           EditText vZeitE = (EditText) findViewById(vZeit);
                            checkDefaultTime();
```

The problem is that it shows me that data is missing, but doesn't stop to let me repair the missing data, just goes further, executing the other remaining lines from the method, regardless that the fields' length is 0.

In this case I used it to store the values for each field in prefereces, later to be able to load this values. Before I could not save this values unless evety field's length was >0, now, even if length is 0, something is stored there, and if I load the data and try to do the math, obviously it crashes the app.

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong ? why in one case it works and in the other just goes to the next line ... ignoring the fact that field length should not be 0 ... ?!

Thank you !

Comment: Make a class and pass EditText maybe this way u will get rid of your problem.!

Comment: I guess you need to do all validations one "onClick" higher. That is in the onclick of buttoSaveCalcOR, not in the Positive-OnClick of the AlertDialog.

Comment: 1. Atif AbbAsi thank you for your input but I forgot to tell you my java skills are -2 on a scale from 0 to 10 :P, so I have almost no idea what you are telling me.
2. Flidor - no joy, it does not work as you said. but thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make `checkBeginnTime()` return a boolean, if field is OK return true, else return false,

and based on `checkBeginnTime()` result, proceed or stop the process:

```
public boolean checkBeginnTime() {
    EditText EtimpAnfang = (EditText) findViewById(timpAnfang);
    if (EtimpAnfang.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        EtimpAnfang.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(EtimpAnfang, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        EtimpAnfang.setError(getString(R.string.ErrStringAnfangZeitMissing));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the usage part (buttoSaveCalcOR onClick):

```
//:
//:
EditText edTimpAnfang = (EditText) findViewById(timpAnfang);
if(!checkBeginnTime()){
    return;
}
//:
//:
```

**Note:** there is other ways, flexable, to validate all EditTexts in a View (in a screen) i can show you a sample if you want, but it may look little bit complex, unless you are OK with learning few new things.

i am saying this because what you did is not what you really need, because you still have to make a method for each view?!, and call it, so at least you may pass the View (EditText) to the method, this way you can call same method several times.

Comment: You my friend just made my day ! This works exactly as it was intended in the first place. THANK YOU ! The definition part of the method, as above, I am almost sure that I understand how it works and what it does. I did not understood the method calling how it works. IF it is not too much please try to explain what it does. For example why is the method called with ! in front of the name and what does "return;" do. only IF still have the time and mood. THANK YOU AGAIN !

Comment: @Robert hahaha i see you are pretty good using IF :), it's not about mood, it's something i can't explain in a comment, or even in an answer, you can read basic tutorials for that. it's pretty simple, but a quick explanation, `if(expression){}else{}` when expression result is TRUE, the first block is executed, and when expression result is FALSE, then the second (else) block is executed, else is optional, last thing `!` means NOT, it reverses the boolean (!true -> false) and (!false -> true), checkBeginnTime() returns result false if something is wrong, so if(!false){force user to enter value}

Comment: @Robert now when to return true and when to return false, and when to use `!` or not use `!`, it all depends on what you name the method (what is expected result) so if we call the method `isUserInputOK()` then this method should return true if input is not empty, and thus, `if(!isUserInputOK()){force user input}` became more readable and more logical for us (humans) same method can be called `shouldForceUserInput()` this time, this method should return true if user input is empty... bottom line, it depends on you, what are you doing in that method, and what true or false means based on that